# Hide and show input doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
 var getInput = document.querySelector('.search-form')
var screenWidth;
var getWidth;
var bodyDisplay;
var display;

window.onresize = function(event) {
 screenWidth = event.target.outerWidth;
};


     

function getCssProperty(elmId, property){
     var elem = document.getElementById(elmId);
     return window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(property);
}

      
function showInput() {

 if(screenWidth === null){
  screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
 }
 if(display === 'none' && screenWidth > 959){
  getInput.style.display = 'inline-block';
  document.querySelector('.search-field').focus();
 } else {
  getInput.style.display = 'none';
 }
      
}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick=function(){
 display = getCssProperty('search-field', 'display');
 if(bodyDisplay === 'inline-block') {
  getInput.style.display = 'none';
 } else {}
};
```

```css
.search-container {
  background: #fff;
}

.search-form {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.search-field {
  margin: 0;
}

.search-field:hover,
.search-field:focus {
  border: 1px solid #0cb4ce;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showInput()">Press here</button>
 <form action="#" class="search-form" id="search-field" method="get">
  <div class="search-container-inner">
   <input type="search" class="search-field form-fluid" placeholder="search" value="" name="s" title="test">
  </div>
    </form>
```

This code hides and shows the input when the button is clicked. The problem is i also want to make it when i click on the body to hide the input, but this detects clicks on the button too and its not showing the input at all, the input is always display:none. What am I doing wrong and how can i do it?

Comment: You have to check if you clicked on the button, too, or only on the body. If you click on the button, both onclick functions are called, because the button also belongs to the body.

Comment: yeah, i realised that but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var getInput = document.querySelector('.search-form')
var screenWidth;
var getWidth;
var bodyDisplay;
var display;

window.onresize = function(event) {
    screenWidth = event.target.outerWidth;
};

function getCssProperty(elmId, property){
        var elem = document.getElementById(elmId);
        return window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(property);
}

function showInput(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event.target.className);
    if(event.target.className == "search-field form-fluid") return;
    if(screenWidth === undefined){  //screenWidth is undefined but not null
     screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    }
    console.log(screenWidth ,"b")
    if(display === undefined && screenWidth > 500){ //display is undefined but not null
        getInput.style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.querySelector('.search-field').focus();
    display = true; //setting display true as a flag 
    } else {
    display=undefined; // making display undefined so that again on click if loop will execute
        getInput.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick=function(event){
  console.log("body")
    display= true; // if true else loop in showInput will execute

  showInput(event);
};
```

Note: For demo and to replicate in jsfiddle I have changed checking `screenwidth >500`. you can change it in your code .

the body part is marked with red border.

Check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/pLvf0pm4/1/)

Your code was correct but problem was user can not enter a text in input becouse it get hide also. So I have added two line of code below

> event.stopPropagation();

Thanks